# Can't use Google Cloud Platform connection in Airflow 1.10.4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I tried to update my airflow (1.10.3) to the new version (1.10.4) and my dags which uses PostgresToGoogleCloudOperator start to fail because I can't connect with Google Cloud Connection previous created.

Apparently the operator is trying to find my key_file with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment var.

When I rollback to 1.10.3 my dags works again.

Anyone knows something about a new form of connection in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

According to the notes on the update here there are breaking changes. [airflow/UPDATING.md](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md)

Specifically for  Google Cloud Connection:

> Moved provide_gcp_credential_file decorator to GoogleCloudBaseHook
>   To simplify the code, the decorator has been moved from the inner-class.
>
> Instead of @GoogleCloudBaseHook._Decorators.provide_gcp_credential_file, you should write @GoogleCloudBaseHook.provide_gcp_credential_file

Comment: According with this file, that update you mentioned only affects the master branch. The version 1.10.4 do not uses that yet I believe, but I found a topic which mentions the change in google cloud storage API, probably my problem is related to that.